# Reuse an email address with a leaked password

Tags: passwords, email, password-management, password-policy

I just found that the password of a very old email address was leaked. I did not use this email address for a long time cause I lost its password. But now that the password is out, I'm thinking of using it again.

How dangerous is it to use the leaked password to login and then of course change it? What are the security risks ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take your email back if you can pass the "lost password" methods provided, after that you must verify if some unintended user has changed the recovery methods in such a way that he could have it back at any time. After that the only real problem is that it's likely that your email address leaked and you'll be receiving lots of spam email, much more than before. Maybe also he registered in some site (porn/games sites for example) using your email so the spamming goes to you.